# Change div shadow on click and back on next

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div with a red box shadow change it's CSS (different color for example).

But I'm also trying to make it change back (for usage of bootstrap collapse)

All I've found so far is this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".sbox").click(function () {
        $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 30px blue');
    });
});
</script>
```

But this only changes it once but not back.

The current css looks like:

```
.sbox {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 15%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px #960000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Can't seem to find anything else

Comment: you will need to keep track of the shadow/non-shadow state with a variable or some other method and then either add the property or remove it (try setting to `unset`) based on the state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, try using `toggleClass`.

Addl. css:

```
.sboxOpen {
     box-shadow: 0 0 30px blue;
}
```

Your script becomes:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".sbox").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('sboxOpen');
    });
});
</script>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nmhrfa8y/4/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

Add param `shadow` for this element:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".sbox").click(function () {
     if($(this).attr('shadow')=='blue'){
       $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 30px #960000').attr('shadow','purple');
     }else{
          $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 30px blue').attr('shadow','blue');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.sbox {
    color: white;
    background-color: #0c0c0c;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 15%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px #960000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sbox">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on pepperjack's answer just for the sake of completion, a [pure JS alternative](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#toggle_class) IE10+.

```
var sbox = document.querySelector('.sbox');
sbox.classList.toggle('sboxOpen');
```